# How to add more than 5 bottom navigation view in android programming?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

Okay so i know it's a bad user experience to having more than 5 navigation view in bottom of any android application and also related library doesn't support it but beside the fact i really want to know, is there anyway i could achieve this.?
like i wanna more than 5 bottom navigation tabs or it might be 6 or 7 tabs in bottom. it's like A,B,C,D,E,F,G

Comment: By rolling your own bottom nav component?

Comment: sry but i didn't get it. i'm looking for third party library for bottom navigation which allows more than 5 navigationview in bottom.